# Check for True or Null value in Linq to Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How to get the true or null records from a table.

Linq to SQL :

```
var result = from entry in table
             where entry.column1== null || entry.column1 == true
             select entry;
```

Get Table data where Column1 = null OR true.
How to implement the same in Linq-to-Entities?

Comment: It's exactly the same. You don't have to make any change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same. You don't have to make any change

Let that `entities` is a collection of your entities, then: you could try exactly  the same:

```
var result = from entity in entities
             where entity.propertyName == null || entity.propertyName == true
             select entity;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply

Comment: @user1893874 You are welcome. I am glad that I helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = table.Where(x => x.column1 == null || x.column1 == true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution